# SSO CAS is not working while returning back from CAS Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, single-sign-on, cas

SSO CAS was working fine before ubuntu security patch update.
Once I update the ubuntu security patch, it is not working. Getting issue while returning back from CAS Server.

Getting below error:

> <cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>\n
> <cas:authenticationFailure code="INVALID_TICKET">Ticket 'ST-231187-6FE0JcCRd4viAFOKts5-p3XWaVH15QFwSNdE7NSwOMXdlMR8PL3tUlNBlgnXlPmCepbCpGGUIbDglJa2-cas.stetson.edu' not recognized</cas:authenticationFailure>\n</cas:serviceResponse>\n in /var/www/html/vendor/jasig/phpcas/source/CAS/Client.php:3278\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/jasig/phpcas/source/CAS/Client.php(1454): CAS_Client->validateCAS20()\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/jasig/phpcas/ in /var/www/html/vendor/jasig/phpcas/source/CAS/Client.php on line 3278,